# Need help in cv2 error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match)

Tags: python, opencv

> error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op'

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Opens the image
image = cv.imread('numbers.jpg')
width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]

resized = cv.resize(image, (int(image.shape[1] * 0.5), int(image.shape[0] * 0.5)), interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
cropped_image = resized[int(width/9.6):int(width/4.8), int(height/4.32):int(height/(54/35))]
print(width, height)
cv.imshow('resized',cropped_image)

# Image processing
blank = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='uint8')
gray = cv.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 120, 255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
inverted_tresh = cv.bitwise_not(thresh)
cv.imshow('thresh', inverted_tresh)

# count white pixels
print(cv.countNonZero(inverted_tresh))
```

This code made the error and I don't understand why:

```
# Shape masking
masked_image = cv.bitwise_and(image, inverted_tresh)
cv.imshow('masked', masked_image)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well from a glance at your code, you're trying to mask the *full* image (not the cropped one) using `inverted_tresh`, which derives from the cropped version. Your error is stating in fact that *arrays do not have the same size and type* in your masking function most likely.

Comment: It seems like when I run this it works:
`
masked_image = cv.bitwise_and(cropped_image, cropped_image, mask=thresh)
cv.imshow('masked', masked_image)`

Comment: that's because both inputs have obviously the same height and width: you can solve this error for instance by rescaling the cropped_image to the full image size, or vice versa downscale your image to the mask size.

Answer (score -1):

This is the write way to mask two objects.

```
# Shape masking
masked_image = cv.bitwise_and(cropped_image, cropped_image, mask=thresh)
cv.imshow('masked', masked_image)
```

cv.waitKey(0)

Comment: You can delete the question if you want. The error is quite clear and there are many duplicates already.